# Node.js REPL parses its input differently with semicolon and without semicolon

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know that JavaScript can interpret {} as an empty block instead of an empty object. I don`t know why Node.js REPL (v12.3.1) behaves differently **with** semicolon and **without** semicolon.

```
>{}+{}
'[object Object][object Object]'
>{}+{};
NaN
```

Comment: @Li357: I do not believe this is a duplicate. There is some mention about expressions vs. statements deep down in the comments below one of the answers, but nothing that answers this question.

Comment: Node is aware that the usual `eval` parse is annoying in many cases when using a REPL, and intelligently interprets text like that as an expression. (It didn’t always.) `{}+{};`, however, can never be an expression.

Comment: Why isn`t {}+{}; expression? From Google Chrome Console: > {}+{}; <- NaN

Comment: @JörgWMittag The linked dupe has exactly the same question, why `{}+{}` results in string concat while `{}+{};` becomes NaN.